# jquery/ajax set charset header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to set the charSet in a jquery call the site I am making is for a Lithuanian friend thus has some letters with accents etc.

As far as my research so far (2 days worth!!!) has shown, I need to place it in the beforeSend section which I have done as follows:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.content').load('home.html');   //by default initally load text from boo.php
     $('#navlist a').click(function() { //start function when any link is clicked
                    $(".content").slideUp("slow");
                     var content_show = $(this).attr("title"); //retrieve title of link so we can compare with php file
                        $.ajax({
                        method: "load",url: ""+content_show,
                        beforeSend: function(){
                            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
                            $("#loading").show("fast");
                        }, //show loading just when link is clicked
                        complete: function(){ $("#loading").hide("fast");}, //stop showing loading when the process is complete
                        success: function(html){ //so, if data is retrieved, store it in html
                        $(".content").show("slow"); //animation
                        $(".content").html(html); //show the html inside .content div
                 }
             }); //close $.ajax(
     }); //close click(
 }); //close $(
```

I have tried changing it to

```
setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
```

Which also does not work, so now I am stuck and at the end of my nerves having looked around for two days.

The website can be viewed at 43dennis.co.nr/bivakas  Basically it loads with a bunch of square black questions marks in place of the letters with special accents.

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh.. with either XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader or just setRequestHeader the function does not even work... sorry forgot to mention that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't going to work due to security restrictions. You need to set the charset in the parent page from where this JS runs. The JS/jQuery will use the same charset.

I checked the HTML of your webpage and I see the following:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

You need to replace `iso-8859-1` by `UTF-8`, then you don't need to hassle with it in JS/jQuery.

I checked the HTTP response headers of your webpage and I see the following:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Sun, 04 Jul 2010 13:37:08 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 600

200 OK
```

The `Content-Type` is missing the `charset` attribute. You also need to set the same in the HTTP response header. Put this in your PHP code, *before* you emit any character into the response body.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: Im not sure where you got that info from but here is the header of my main page which is set to utf-8

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>Bivakas</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

I am not currently using php...

Comment: Just noticed.. that charSet is from the co.nr domain provider... not my website :)

Comment: Then you need to jump out of the frameset. The parent page with the frame is rendering the page in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Bringing and old topic back from the dead but similar to this problem. If you are working in notepad++ remember to check your file encoding. I have had instances where it was ANSI and was causing a headache. Can be changed using the "encoding" menu item.