# Ajax sends wrong charset

Tags: php, html, ajax, json, character-encoding

Ajax is sending to PHP

```
Ĺ&nbsp;asija-kabina
```

Instead of

```
Šasija-kabina
```

While I did declare the charset everwhere.
In the head of the html file I've got this:

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-2">
```

In the PHP file I've got this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=latin2');
```

And this is my ajax function where "str" is a json array:

```
function updateField(str, id, prevvalue, value, vehicletype){
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "inc/ajax/form_rest.php",
        data: { q:str, prevvalue:prevvalue, value:value, vehicletype:vehicletype },
        contentType: "application/json;charset=latin2",
        success: function(html) {
                    $('#'+id).html(html);
                }
        })
        .done(function(){
            $("#"+id).removeAttr("disabled");
            if($("#"+id+" option").length == 2){
                $("#"+id).val($("#"+id+" option:last-child").val()).change();
            }
            if($("#"+id+" option:last-child").val() == ""){
                $("#"+id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
}
```

Nevertheless I am getting the wrong output. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Just a guess, why not utf-8?

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't work I tried it. It shows question marks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't set the `contentType` from within `$.ajax`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175091/jquery-ajax-set-charset-header

Comment: This was my source for the contentType thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285936/how-to-change-ajax-charset AndI tried what was said in your link but it still shows question marks in black diamonds for those characters

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the correct ISO name for the character set, e.g. change:

```
contentType: "application/json;charset=latin2",
```

to

```
contentType: "application/json;charset=ISO-8859-2",
```

I also think that using anything other than UTF-8 is going to get you in more trouble later in your project as json_encode in PHP really only supports UTF-8.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution did not work either.. And when I use UTF-8 it shows question marks in a diamond for those characters for example the Š

Comment: Where does it show question marks? When you send the data back to the page?

Comment: Well when I change the charset in the head to UTF-8 it shows all the croatian characters as question marks in a black diamond. The website itself is croatian.

Comment: I'd suggest reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through Although you may be able to get this to work with Latin-2, that will still leave you to struggle with interacting with other web services in future.

Answer (score 0):

do you use an external javascript file for this?, I think you need also to set the character set for the inclusion of the javascript file

```
<script src="myscripts.js" charset="latin2"></script>
```

but I really recommend you to use UTF-8 both on server and client side scripts